# Stringing multiple xslt string operations together

Tags: xslt

I am trying to do the following command in xslt 1.0:

```
 <xsl:element name="{substring-before(concat('dc:',substring-after(name(),'.')),'.')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:element>
```

I get a runtime error on the  line, however if I remove the substring-before command on the previous line it works. I am guessing I have made a syntax error somewhere, but not sure what (as I am new to xslt). Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong? I guess an issue might be what does substring-before return if the needle string is not found?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply the runtime error message.

Comment: Also, what is the name of the element, including any namespace prefix, you are currently positioned on? (i.e what does "name()" return?)

Comment: What is the objective of this string operation? The end result will be blank unless the original node name has two periods in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $haystack contains no instances of $needle, then substring-before($haystack,$needle) returns the empty string.

You have not made a syntax error, but you have almost certainly made a logic error.  Let's work our way up.  Assume the current element is named one of `ns:abc`, or `ns:def.ghi` or `ns:jkl.mno.pqr`.

1. The expression `substring-after(name(),'.')` returns '', 'ghi', or 'mno.pqr'.
2. The `concat` expression adds `dc:` to the beginning, so we have 'dc:', 'dc:ghi', or 'dc:mno.pqr'.
3. The full expression searches the concatenation result for '.' and returns either the substring before '.' or the empty string, so we get '', '', and 'pqr' for our three test cases.

If you were guessing that `substring-before` and `substring-after` return the entire string if there is no match, then now you know the truth.

Comment: Yes this was my issue, I checked and noticed it was returning an empty string hence the run time error because element can't be an empty string. Very good explanation which will definitely help out others who might make the same logic error.